# Make calculations in the directive or in the page controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

In a web app built in Angular 1.x, is it better, relative to performance, to make calculations (for example sort arrays, prepare the variables in the $scope that will go to dom's ng-if, etc) in the Controller of Directive which uses these variabiables or is it better to prepare them on the page where the Directive is used, and pass it to the Directive?

Comment: The model-view-controller architecture is about [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to make the design more easily understood, debugged, tested, and maintained. Calculations for the Model should be done in the Controller. Directives should just render the View from the Model. Tangling those concerns makes for difficulty in debugging, testing, and maintenance. Avoid tangled fragile designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise there is no difference as long as you not hitting top count of watchers in any controller (approx. 2000). Difference is only way of sharing data & functionality. If you want to reuse same set of component along with it's associated business logic then create directive so that you can reuse it. And again based on requirement of reusability on same view or different views you can create either isolated scope or shared scope directives respectively and then share the data to directive controller from view's controller